# Prove that $x_{n+1} = x_n ^ {x_n / n}, x_1 = a$ is bounded for all $a < b$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

Consider $x_{n+1} = x_n ^ {x_n / n}, x_1 = a$.
Prove that there exists $b>1$ such that $x_n$ is bounded for all $a < b$ and unbounded otherwise.
I've made some progress on this task, but nothing big. How should I approach this?

Comment: $a<b$ does not make sense. What is $b$?

Comment: I need to prove that there exists such a b that for all a < b $x_n$ is bounded. I don't know what b is, I need to prove there is one

Comment: Whenever $x_n < n$ is reached, your sequence will start decaying monotonically towards 1.  The question is, do the first $x_n$ grow sufficiently slowly for $x_n < n$ to eventually happen?

Comment: Numerically, one finds that $b\approx 1.741669246302\ldots$, which doesn't seem to have an obvious closed representation.

Comment: @DominikS how did you find b? Anyway there’s no need for a representation, I only need to prove that such b exists

Comment: By computing the first few dozen of $x_n$ for different and observing the behavior of the elements for different $b$. Doing a grid search based on that.

Comment: Let $a_n$ denote the unique choice of $a$ obtaining $x_n=n$. See if you can prove: (i) $(a_n)_{n\ge1}$ is a bounded increasing sequence; (ii) $b$ is its supremum.

Answer (score 0):

1. If $b>1$, all $x_n>1$ too.
2. Consider $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$, which are the sequences for different initial $b$. Clearly, if $x_n > y_n$ for some $n$, then $x_{n+1} > y_{n+1}$. This means that if the sequence converges for some $b$, then it will converge for all smaller $b>1$ as well. Analogously, if it diverges for some $b>1$, it will diverge for all greater $b$.
3. Now it clearly converges for $b=1$, because $x_n=1$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$.
4. It diverges for $b = 10$ (just picking any large initial value; some crude estimates should suffice to prove that).

Therefore, there needs to be a value of $1<b<10$ for which the behaviour of the sequence switches from convergent to divergent.